# Sub meter ROS compatible GPS

Tags: ros, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Folks,

I am in need of a GPS device that currently works with ROS that has a better accuracy than 1 meter.

Does anyone have any suggestions or information that could help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199210/sub-meter-ros-compatible-gps/) by [T00Tall](https://answers.ros.org/users/21071/t00tall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clearpath tends to supply the [NovAtel SMART-6](http://www.novatel.com/products/smart-antennas/smart6/) when clients need such accuracy. It'll go down to 2 cm if the right upgrade options are selected, a base station is available,  and everything's configured properly (warning: Don't underestimate the configuration time). It works with the standard navsat driver as well.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [T00Tall](https://answers.ros.org/users/21071/t00tall/) on 2014-12-10**:
Thank you for you're answer. Do you happen to know of any database of nmea compatible devices? To top off my request I forgot to mention we need the device to be relatively small.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-12-11**:
I can't think of any database, no. AFAIK, GPS devices which can't be configured for NMEA output are rare.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run any device that provides you NMEA ASCII output to the serial port in ROS using the nmea_nav_sat_driver http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver.

E. g. we use a predecessor device of TopCon's GR-5 (http://www.topconpositioning.eu/gnss/integrated-gnss-receivers/gr-5) with UTMS RTK support to reach sub meter accuracy; no additional ROS driver needed!

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2